# The difference between "auswirken auf" , "einwirken auf", and "wirken auf"

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, english-to-german, difference

I'm trying to figure out the subtle differences between "auswirken auf" , "einwirken auf", and "wirken auf". Dictionaries tend to all point in the same direction, and that is "impact/have an impact on/etc", but I feel that there is certain emphasis that these words convey, and I'm not able to figure out the difference. Now, I think the easiest (for me) is "sich auf etwas auswirken", which means, "have an effect on". Let me then just give three examples:

1. Der Forscher untersucht, wie Politik auf die Wirtschaft einwirkt.
2. Der Forscher untersucht, wie sich Politik auf die Wirtschaft auswirkt.
3. Der Forscher untersucht, wie Politik auf die Wirtschaft wirkt.

Are both sentences correct, and is there a large difference between the two? My first guess is., 1. ... how politics INfluences the economy, and 2. ...how politics impacts... but I am not quite sure. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I hope I didn't put too much into your mouth regarding your examples, though you are asking for 3 terms, and such I corrected your originally wrong sentence, and added that other one, where the _sich_ makes sense.

Comment: No, this is perfectly fine. You are right, I could have left "auswirken" out, because I feel confident in its meaning, and am more concerned the other two. I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: I tried to give a concise answer. I am just a native German speaker, with some experienced knowledge about English though. There might be more linguistically founded answers fro that, just wait for a while.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Warum genau? Für mich nicht.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Und von der Politik geht nichts ein in die Wirtschaft oder wie? Warum betreiben wir dann ein Wirtschaftsministerium das den Steuerzahler ein Heidengeld kostet bitte?

Comment: After the third sentence was added as 2nd list item, is your reference ("My first guess is., 1. […] and 2. […]") still correct?

Answer (score 2):

In fact the differences are a bit subtle, and not well distinguished using popular dictionaries (e.g. dict.leo.org [1](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/einwirken), [2](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/auswirken), [3](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/wirken%20auf)).

Also Google Translate isn't very helpful with this, since all three examples will lead to the same translation as

> The researcher examines how politics affects the economy.

I think that there's a subtle emphasis in German, that *einwirken* has a more active connotation, while *auswirken* or *wirken* doesn't express that.

I'd translate

> Der Forscher untersucht, wie Politik auf die Wirtschaft einwirkt.
>
> > The researcher examines how politics influences<sup>1</sup> the economy.

and

> Der Forscher untersucht, wie Politik auf die Wirtschaft einwirkt.
> Der Forscher untersucht, wie Politik auf die Wirtschaft wirkt.
>
> > The researcher examines how politics impacts<sup>1</sup> the economy.

---

It's worth to mention, that *wirken auf* also means which view/impression someone leaves for anyone else, and is a term on it's own.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>In English *to influence* has a stronger active connotation than *to impact*.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic answer. Let me then ask, if we consider "...wie die Politik die Wirtschaft beeinflusst", according to my (slowly growing :) ) knowledge of German, I could translate this as "influence" as well. Is the distinction the following:

1. "..die Wirtschaft beeinflusst": Simply "influences the economy".
2. "..auf die Wirtschaft einwirkt". Like Janka suggested, how it influences/interacts with, so, emphasizing not the ending effects (as in beeinflussen), but the particular WAYS in which this change is made.

Could this be correct?

Comment: @Mark Regarding the _active_ connotation _beeinflussen_ is the _"magic word"_ here.

Comment: According to this dictionary (https://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/einwirken), "auf etwas einwirken=etwas beeinflussen". But you suggest that beeinflussen is more active?

Comment: @Mark If it's clear that a _person_ or _institution_ does it, yes.

Comment: @Mark _Einwirken_ is still much stronger.

Comment: If I said, "Die gute Laune des Chefs wirkt positiv auf unsere Produktivität ein", could I then translate this as, "positively influences"?

Comment: @Mark Yes, that sounds to be correct and transports the emphasis.

Comment: How about this. "Sich einwirken auf=einen Einfluß ausüben auf"=exert an influence on, die beiden sind mit "influence" verbunden, aber "exert an influence" ist viel stärker, und sehr aktiv

Comment: @Mark _exert_ unterstreicht die aktive Konnotation nochmals, ja.

Comment: I think we have solved it!

Answer (score 2):

**Wirken** means *to cause an effect/to be effective*:

> Das Waschmittel wirkt.

**Einwirken** means *to act upon/to interact*:

> Das Waschmittel muss erst einwirken.

**Bewirken** means *to cause the primary effect*:

> Das Waschmittel bewirkt, dass der Schmutz sich leichter vom Stoff löst.

**Auswirken** means *to cause a secondary effect*:

> Waschmittel wirken sich negativ auf die Umwelt aus.

---

And finally, there's the unrelated **verwirken**, which means *to forfeit*.

Comment: Ich dachte an mehr oder weniger dieselben Beispiele als ich die Frage las.

Comment: Politik ist ein abstraktes Thema. Was da nun genau wirkt, einwirkt, sich auswirkt, kann man kaum bestimmen. Oft bewirkt sie ja auch einfach nichts.

Comment: @Janka _"Oft bewirkt sie ja auch einfach nichts."_ Im Beispiel geht's ja darum, genau das zu erforschen. :3

Comment: Thank you. So, if I say, "...wie Politik auf die Wirtschaft einwirkt.", is that then emphasizing the specific ways/channels politics "acts upon/interacts with" the economy?. For example, if somebody acts, "Wie wirkt die Maßnahme auf die Wirtschaft ein?", the answer cannot be "good" or "bad", but rather, for example it interacts/acts upon the economy because it changes a specific tax.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that question asks about the way or location (*Wo wirkt … ein?*) that measure works. *Gut* or *schlecht* is only a secondary effect, and required *sich auswirken*.